# Ask for an algorithm for sub-ordering a sub-array of an already sorted super-array

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Suppose I have already sorted an array $a$ of length $N$, each element having its position index into the sorted result recorded together with the element. Now I randomly sampled a sub-array $b$ of the original array $a$ without putting back (that is, no duplicated elements). Since the position index is recorded together with the data element, I have this information when given the sub-array. The sub-array $b$ was obtained in a random manner, so I need to sub-order the sub-array $b$ so that it is sorted. The length of $b$ is around 1% of that of $a$. I wish to make use of the position index contained together with each data element of $b$ so that I don't have to sort $b$ afresh and that the complexity of sub-sorting $b$ is linear or even logarithmic with regard to the length of $b$. I thought for a couple of days but couldn't figure out one such sub-sorting algorithm. Can you please give me some hint or help? Thank you.

Comment: Using the *position index*, each comparison should take constant time which need not be true for the *data element*s. FWIW, I don't see any short-cut.

Comment: Have you considered [integer sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting)? I think this might help since you can now sort based on the indices and there is no need to perform comparison between values.